# Python asyncio callback from another thread

Tags: python-asyncio

There are many question on threads and asyncio on stackoverflow but I have not yet found my answer. I have a callback in another thread than the asyncio loop, that callback can't be a coroutine due to external library define the signature and calls it. I would like to call a coroutine from that callback, but I do NOT want to wait or block for that call to finish, since that will hold up the external library. In short how to schedule a coroutine from another thread, to run as soon as possible. Some test code, if the call to f.result() is removed the on_message is not scheduled or we get complaints on that it is not awaited.

```
    def _on_message(self, consumer, message):
        f = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.on_message(consumer, message), self.loop)
        # don't want this blocking call to result
        f.result()

    async def on_message(self, consumer, message):
        # do real work
        pass
```

Comment: If `on_message` is not **scheduled** (i.e. `on_message` doesn't run at all), that likely means that something is wrong with your event loop, e.g. it's not running or is blocked by something else. Can you create a minimal runnable example that shows the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to `run_in_executor` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor . What kind of external library is this ? Is it a web framework ?

Comment: @JoseKilo `run_in_executor` will not help the OP because they want to schedule a coroutine to execute from a sync callback. `run_in_executor` is when you need the inverse, executing sync code from inside a coroutine. `run_coroutine_threadsafe` is designed for exactly the OP's use case.

Comment: Sorry currently I don't have a small example, but from what I can see the on_message does not even get scheduled without the call to result(). The asyncio loop is very busy, so it might be that it would get scheduled if not a lot of other coroutines were waited for, which are scheduled. The external libraries I have these issues with are for example paho-mqtt and pulsar-client, both allow registering callbacks for subscriptions.

Comment: *Sorry currently I don't have a small example, but from what I can see the on_message does not even get scheduled without the call to result()* Are you sure of that? Have you tried replacing `f.result()` with `time.sleep(5)` (or however long it takes to get to the result)?

Comment: If you mean that the whole program would end before it eventually got called, it is not it is continuously running, I have a while True loop in the asyncio loop thread doing things regularly and doing asyncio.sleep in periods in between.

Comment: (You haven't mentioned me as @user4815162342 so I haven't seen your response in time.) I meant literally - have you tried replacing `f.result()` with `time.sleep(5)` (if the coroutine takes up to 5 seconds to compute)? I am trying to understand how you came to the conclusion that "on_message does not even get scheduled without the call to result()".

Comment: @user4815162342 Hi, I came to the conclusion since the program is running and other activity is scheduled but not the on_message. The program runs for a long time, many minutes so the process is not ended. But the scope in which the async call to `on_message` is ended, which a sleep would prevent. The whole purpose is to return on the call to `_on_message` as quickly as possible.

Comment: Have you tried making two versions of the program that are identical in every respect, except that one calls `f.result()` and the other doesn't call `f.result()`, but sleeps for the approximate period that the `f.result()` would sleep for? It would be quite surprising if the first version scheduled `on_message`, but the second didn't.